# Prestashop 1.6: How to make subcategories appear in a filter on the layered navigation block?

Tags: filter, categories, prestashop-1.6

I am trying to make different subcategories of a given categories C to show in a filter on the layered navigation block. Category C has multiple subcategories and the sub-categories filter is abled in the "layered navigation Block" module but for some reason this particular filter is not showing!

Thanks for the help

Answer (score 0):

Did you set the depth in configuration of the module?
Go to modules->modules, and find the layered navigation module. Click configure

Almost the bottom you can change the categories depth (set to 0 for unlimited, or to the max depth you use)

If still you have problem uninstall and reinstall the layered navigation module.